# applescript - attachment at begining of email

Tags: email, applescript

I am running some applescript.  The purpose is to open Mac Mail and create a new message with an attachment that is located on the users' desktop.

It IS currently working, BUT ... the attachment is being inserted AFTER the email signature and we need the attachment to be located in front of the email signature (at the beginning of the email).

thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Code is below ...

```
set theAttachment to "{theDesktopPath and file name}"
set RecipientAddress to "joe@joe.com"
set RecipientName to "Joe"
set TheSubject to "Estimate"

tell application ”Mail”
set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, visible:true}
tell newMessage
make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:RecipientAddress}
tell content of newMessage
make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias} at after the last paragraph
end tell
end tell
activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "after the last" to "before the first" like so:

```
set theAttachment to "{theDesktopPath and file name}"
set RecipientAddress to "joe@joe.com"
set RecipientName to "Joe"
set TheSubject to "Estimate"

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:TheSubject, visible:true}
    tell newMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:RecipientName, address:RecipientAddress}
        tell content of newMessage
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias} at before the first paragraph
        end tell
    end tell
    activate
end tell
```